# One-to-one or many-to-one mapping using primary key of each table

Tags: nhibernate, nhibernate-mapping

I've got a legacy schema with a main table and secondary table, where the secondary table connects to the main table by having the same primary key (a Secondary doesn't not necessarily exist for a given Main).  I've been searching up-and-down for XML mappings that will make this work but haven't found anything that works for me.

```
  <class name="Secondary" table="Secondary" lazy="true" dynamic-insert="true" dynamic-update="true">
    <id name="mainId" type="Int32">
      <column name="MAIN_ID" not-null="true" />
      <generator class="foreign">
        <param name="property">Main</param>
      </generator>
    </id>
    <one-to-one class="Main" name="Main" constrained="true" />
  </class>


  <class name="Main" table="Main" lazy="true" dynamic-insert="true" dynamic-update="true">
    <one-to-one name="Secondary" cascade="all-delete-orphan" class="Secondary" />
```

Also tried  on the Main side, still no go.  It doesn't necessarily break, but it certainly doesn't do what I expect.  For example:

`session.Query<Main>().Count(m => m.Secondary != null)` generates

```
select
    cast(count(*) as INT) as col_0_0_ 
from
    MAIN main0_ 
where
    main0_.MAIN_ID is not null
```

Note that it's using the MAIN_ID from the MAIN table and is ignoring Secondary altogether.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This issue is fixed in NHibernate 5.3

It's a known [issue](https://github.com/nhibernate/nhibernate-core/issues/1274) (PR with suggested fix is [here](https://github.com/nhibernate/nhibernate-core/pull/2081)).

For now as a workaround in LINQ you can call `Count` on some non-ID and not-nullable property:

```
session.Query<Main>().Count(m => m.Secondary.NotNullableProperty != null)
```

If such property doesn't exist (or you just want to easily find all such hacky usages in future) you can additionally map your Id column as read-only property and use it instead:

```xml
<property name="ForceJoinId" not-null="true" column="MAIN_ID" insert="false" update="false" />
```

```
session.Query<Main>().Count(m => m.Secondary.ForceJoinId != null)
```